# Assist me in finding the error: invalid method declaration; return type required

Tags: java

This is my last homework for my java class and I have been trying to run this through a compiler but I don't understand whats wrong with the code.

I tried using void after reading about how that would fix the return type issue but that just made it worse, maybe I was putting void in the wrong place.

```
public class Exercise09_01 {
    private double width = 1;
    private double height = 1;

    public Rectangle() {
    }

    public Rectangle(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle rectangle1 = new Rectangle(4, 40);
        System.out.println("The area of a 4.0 x 40.0 Rectangle is " + 
        rectangle1.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of a 4.0 x 40.0 Rectangle is " + 
        rectangle1.getPerimeter());
        Rectangle rectangle2 = new Rectangle(3.5, 35.9);
        System.out.println("The area of a 3.5 x 35.9 Rectangle is " + 
        rectangle2.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of a 3.5 x 35.9 Rectangle is " + 
        rectangle2.getPerimeter());
    }
}
```

This is my last homework for this class I just want this over with any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your class name does not match your constructor name(s). They must match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor name should have the same name as the class name

```
    public class Exercise09_01 {
        private double width = 1;
        private double height = 1;

        public Exercise09_01() {
        }

        public Exercise09_01(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
            width = newWidth;
            height = newHeight;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer? Code only answers don't really help anyone, especially future readers.

Comment: the constructor name should have the same name as the class name

Comment: Can you explain that in your question, not in the comments. Future readers may not read the comments when they find this answer.

Comment: sorry mate , could you at least approve it as good answer :) ?

Comment: I took your advice and turn every rectangle to exercise09_01 and it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public Rectangle() {
}
```

This is a method as far as Java is concerned. And all methods have to have  a return type.

```
public Rectangle(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
width = newWidth;
  height = newHeight;
  }
```

The same here.

You don't need the 1st one really unless you really need to be able to make one without those values set.

You can just rename them, but you probably just want to rename the class `Rectangle`

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong in your code is your class name and constructor names are different.

You have two options, one is to rename the constructor to `Exercise01_01` or meke the return type of the `Rectangle` as void.

```
public class Exercise01_01 {

    private double width = 1;
    private double height = 1;

    public Exercise01_01() {
    }

    public Exercise01_01(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
        width = newWidth;
        height = newHeight;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return width * height;
    }

    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2 * (width + height);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise01_01 rectangle1 = new Exercise01_01(4, 40);
        System.out.println("The area of a 4.0 x 40.0 Rectangle is " + rectangle1.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of a 4.0 x 40.0 Rectangle is " + rectangle1.getPerimeter());
        Exercise01_01 rectangle2 = new Exercise01_01(3.5, 35.9);
        System.out.println("The area of a 3.5 x 35.9 Rectangle is " + rectangle2.getArea());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of a 3.5 x 35.9 Rectangle is " + rectangle2.getPerimeter());
    }

}
```

Comment: My homework has to work in https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/CheckExercise/faces/CheckExercise.xhtml and it requires the class name and file name to be Exercise9_01.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Exercise09_01 {
private double width = 1;
private double height = 1;

public Exercise09_01() {
}

public Exercise09_01(double newWidth, double newHeight) {
width = newWidth;
height = newHeight;
}

public double getArea() {
return width * height;
}

public double getPerimeter() {
return 2 * (width + height);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
Exercise09_01 rectangle1 = new Exercise09_01(4, 40);
System.out.println("The area of a 4.0 x 40.0 Rectangle is " + rectangle1.getArea());
System.out.println("The perimeter of a 4.0 x 40.0 Rectangle is " + 
rectangle1.getPerimeter());
Exercise09_01 rectangle2 = new Exercise09_01(3.5, 35.9);
System.out.println("The area of a 3.5 x 35.9 Rectangle is " + rectangle2.getArea());
System.out.println("The perimeter of a 3.5 x 35.9 Rectangle is " + 
rectangle2.getPerimeter());
}
}
```

Thanks for all the help and this is the code that passes through the compiler. Just leaving it here for future visitors.